# Messed up boot for Acer Aspire 5

Tags: windows-10, command-line, partitioning, grub, acer-aspire

I got a brand new Acer Aspire 5 A515-51G-8227 and, despite it saying it has a free OS I found out it had this thing called Endless OS. Fair enough, I got a windows 10 USB, booted from legacy, opened the installation and messed up tremendously.

There were 5 partitions and I obviously tried to install on the biggest one - turns out the OS was there. Anyway, as I was trying to install windows I was informed the SSD was formatted in GPT so I need a GPT USB to install. After restarting I can't boot anything anymore in UEFI and in Legacy it only boots into grub rescue.

I have searched the internet and most people who ended up with this had a dual boot and could just use that to fix their problems. I don't...
Is there anything I can do to install Windows (I need to dual boot it with a Linux distribution too)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, the solution.

Your first option would be to install in legacy mode as opposed to UEFI but for Windows 8 and after that's a poor idea.

In UEFI you need to set up a supervisor password and you can disable secure boot. From then on you should be able to boot into your USB and install from the EFI shell. If you get an error saying you miss bootx64.efi, you need to download [this](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/EdkShellBinPkg/MinimumShell/X64/Shell.efi) and rename it to bootx64.efi and put it in the efi/boot/ folder on your USB.

If you can't boot at all, make sure you wrote the USB in NTFS:UEFI.